# Is there any way to update the Unity in Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, unity

Is there any way to update the Unity (dash, launcher, etc.) in Ubuntu 11.04? For example could I make it what Ubuntu 11.10 has? (The dash contains icons for applications, places, etc at the bottom).

If this is possible, please say how I can do it.. Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

As many of you have asked/suggested to upgrade to 11.10, I cannot do this currently as my 3G modem does not work with Ubuntu 11.10 (I tested this on 2 computers with the same result) and this modem is my only means to connect to the internet. So I guess I have to wait until 12.04 comes out.. :(

Comment: May I ask why won't you just upgrade to 11.10?

Comment: @rafalcieslak I did it, but my modem won't work then. Please see my updated question..

Comment: Did you open a question about your modem or report a bug?

Comment: @RolandTaylor I opened a question here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/82341/huwawei-e220-broadband-dongle-not-working But it was a bug.. And the only workaround is to execute a shell command every time and replug the device (and that's too much of a hassle).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been covered before I think (though the other question was a bit different and never had an accepted answer), and the answer is no, because updating Unity requires updating other libraries which could break your system. Your best bet is to upgrade to 11.10 or 12.04 (when it comes out).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I guess I'll have to wait till Ubuntu 12.04 comes out (my modem won't work in 11.10. See my updated question). But then again, who knows my modem will work even then?

Answer (score 1):

Not the best choice to update to 11.04. My experience showed that 11.04 behaves with my Sony VAIO S11. the best, I had a lot of incidents on 11.10, starting from network and ending the display. Also, I found that Unity is more stable on 11.04 (OMG)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I had no choice actually as my modem won't work in Ubuntu 11.10 (see my updated question) and 10.10 is too outdated. So I upgraded to 11.04 and beside the unity launcher "working-really-great-and-I'm-lovin-it", I didn't encounter any other errors.. So have to wait till 12.04 (and have my fingers crossed).. :)