# Huawei E8372h-927 Modem configuration not working on Ubuntu 14.04 lts

Tags: networking, drivers, usb-modem, modem, 4g

1. I'm having trouble with my broadband modem (Huawei E8372h-927) on Ubuntu 14.04 . I have install divers for (Huawei E8372h-927) as per installation procedure are as follows:

   1. Installatiion

      a. To install the Linux Driver tool only:

      ```
      call the following command in the installation directory:
      ./install $PATH (The parameter "PATH" is where the driver directory is)
      And the can copy usbmod file to /sbin/
           copy startMobilePartner file to /sbin/
           copy 10-Huawei-Datacard.rules file to /etc/udev/rules.d/
           register the auto run settengs into the current system.
      To make the settings applied, you must restart the system.
      ```

      b. To integrated the Linux Driver tool into the third dashboard application:

      ```
      call "install norestart" in the installation tool of the third dashboard application. 
      This call scheme will disable the restarting function in the tool installation.
      And after the third dashboard application installed, its installation tool must restart the current system.
      ```
   2. To inquire about the version of the Linux Driver tool,
      call `HWActivator --version`.
   3. The current version is : Linux Driver 4.19.19.00

And after `dmesg` does't show as connected to usb. That's why when I have dial wvdialconf /etc/wvdial.conf command it shows no modem found ..

Please kindly update me for the same.

Comment: would you please simply give us the link which you followed to perform the manual installation of drivers or whatever you're trying to say in the question?

Comment: for driver installation  i would use    below link and download tar file from below link and follows installtion procedure                                                                                                         http://tipsformypc.blogspot.in/2015/03/how-to-install-any-huawei-modem-on.html?m=1

Comment: The link you gave does not suggest any of the procedure you followed to install the drivers. What was suggested is far from what have you done. :( I don't know where you find those instructions(that you have given in the question).

Comment: the above instructions  are given given in Readme file in the driver folder  and also ./install $PATH here actually what is $PATH ?? i am still in trouble

Comment: currently i have use only ./install and don't know about $PATH???

Comment: please suggest me procedure of driver installation..

Comment: As written in the 'readme' file, $PATH is the path of directory/folder where the drivers are.

Comment: i have save driver folder in /root and used ./install  /          but still did'n't conncted  in usb mode

Comment: Please see this, if it helps: http://askubuntu.com/questions/82341/huwawei-e220-broadband-dongle-not-working

Comment: i have tried but still same error . is there any alternate solution or link for download the drivers

Comment: is there any wifi related packages installation issue ???  how to configure wifi packages in it?

Comment: Sorry brother, I have no idea.:(